# Zeppelin configuration: is there a cache somewhere?

Tags: apache-zeppelin

It appears I'm missing something in the way Zeppelin reads interpreter specific configuration.

For example I set `spark.cores.max` to 12 in `zeppelin-env.sh` and in the `spark-defaults.sh` in `$SPARK_HOME/conf` but starting the Spark interpreter was starting a Spark Application with only 4 cores.

Then I changed that property in the interpreter UI of Zeppelin and it worked.

- Where are the properties, set using the UI (webpage) stored?
- is that UI supposed to be 'in sync' with `zeppelin-env.sh` or `zeppelin-site.xml`?

Comment: The UI isn't synced with the files you mentioned. So did you stop the deamon, run `bash zeppelin-env.sh` and restarted ot ?

Comment: Yes. I assume the UI saves something somewhere? There is a persistence even after restarting the daemon, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hierarchy here:

- parameters in the UI (interpreter) takes precedence over what is specified in `zeppelin-env.sh`;
- parameters configured in `zeppelin-env.sh` takes precedence over what is specified in `spark-defaults.sh`; and,
- if nothing is specified using the above, configuration parameters fall-back to those specified in `spark-defaults.sh`.

There is an important duality here, with respect to what one would expect with any spark application:

- configuration parameters explicitly set within an application take precedence over those specified with `spark-submit`;
- parameters specified with `spark-submit` take precedence over those specified in `spark-defaults.sh`; and,
- if nothing is specified using the above, then configuration parameters fall-back to those specified in `spark-defaults.sh`.

So what you are observing is to be expected, although I too find it confusing (and not particularly well documented anywhere).

Comment: This sounds very clear to me. Where are the parameters of the UI (interpreter) saved/stored?

Comment: Try `conf/interpreter.json`

Comment: Rhaaaaa. Finally :) The universe makes sense again!

Comment: At least for the next 30s :-)

Comment: Just a small follow-up because the zeppelin configurations messed up my mind for some time. If someone changes the configuration parameters inside the `zeppelin-env.sh` a simple restart of the Zeppelin server wont result in any changes. In order this to happen you can safely delete the old `interpreter.json` file and a new one with your new configurations will take its place. I dont want to make changes from the UI since I would like to allocate specific resources for the zeppelin service before starting up. Finally, this wont affect your notebooks since they are placed in another directory.